# sql query return null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was using the exact same query to get data from two tables. when i dont use the `c.IsReceived  = 0` part, it returns Dates but it doesn't return anything when it is used. There are rows in `RepDailyCollection` with `IsReceived = 0` for `RepID = 205`. What do you think i am doing wrong? This is in 2005 SQL Server. thnak you!!

```
Select 
  distinct RepDailyInfo.Date 
from 
  RepDailyInfo 
left outer join 
  RepDailyCollection c 
on 
  c.RepDailyCollectionID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
where 
  RepDailyInfo.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = 0
```

Edit:

When i use an other stored proc similar to this works fine.

```
Select i.Date
--i.RepDailyInfoID, i.RepID, i.TypeofDayID, i.CommuniTeeID, sum(cast(c.AmountSold as    numeric(10,2))) as AmountSold, 
--  sum(cast (c.AmountCollected as numeric(10,2))) as AmountCollected, c.NewCompanyName,c.PaymentMethod, 
--  c.TypeofCreditCard, c.CheckNumber, c.Invoice, c.Spots, TypeofDay.TypeofDay, CommuniTee.City, CommuniTee.State, 
--  CommuniTee.year, SalesRep_Info.FirstName, SalesRep_Info.LastName
from RepDailyInfo i
left outer join RepDailyCollection c on i.RepDailyInfoID = c.RepDailyInfoID 
left outer join TypeOfDay on TypeOfDay.TypeofDayID = i.TypeofDayID
left outer join SalesRep_Info on SalesRep_Info.RepID = i.RepID
left outer join CommuniTee on CommuniTee.CommuniTeeID = i.CommuniTeeID
 where i.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = 0 
 group by i.RepDailyInfoID, i.Date, i.TypeofDayID, i.CommuniTeeID, SalesRep_Info.FirstName, TypeofDay.TypeofDay, 
CommuniTee.City, CommuniTee.State, CommuniTee.year, SalesRep_Info.FirstName, 
SalesRep_Info.LastName, i.RepID, c.NewCompanyName, c.PaymentMethod, c.TypeofCreditCard, c.CheckNumber, c.Invoice, c.Spots
order by SalesRep_Info.FirstName desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

In the first query you have:

```
Select 
  distinct RepDailyInfo.Date 
from 
  RepDailyInfo 
left outer join 
  RepDailyCollection c 
on 
  c.RepDailyCollectionID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
where 
  RepDailyInfo.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = 0
```

Even though you say "left outer join", due to the where clause you may as well have said inner join.

Regardless, this query doesn't match the second one.  In the second query you are joining RepDailyCollection to RepDailyInfo on **RepDailyInfoID**.  In the first query you are joining on completely different columns.

Comment: You are right Chris. I have messed up the queries. :-( I understand what might have gone wrong. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Where you have "LEFT JOIN ... ON ... = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID", should that actually be "LEFT JOIN ... ON ... = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyCollectionID"?

Comment: Please see the edit part, it works fine and gives me the dates but not the real question i asked..

Comment: I'm glad you got your answer.  I just know I tend not to get any results when I mismatch the fields I'm joining to.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a varchar/char field?

```
c.IsReceived = '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be records in `RepDailyCollection` with `IsReceived = 0` and `RepID = 205`, but if there aren't any records in `RepDailyInfo` with the repid of 205 then no records will be returned because of your where clause.

Based on your statement

> There are rows in RepDailyCollection with IsReceived = 0 for RepID = 205

It sounds like your where clause should be:

```
c.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = 0
```

instead of

```
RepDailyInfo.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but i do have Rows in RepDailyInfo with RepID = 205

Comment: There isn't a column RepID in RepDailyCollection. I double checked :-( Is the issue because of the join??

Comment: Please look at the edit part of the question? Though i can get the results using the edited part, i am wondering what was wrong with the initial question i asked.. Thanks for your time @abe

Answer (score 0):

for your testing .. you can do following query..

```
Select distinct c.IsReceived from RepDailyInfo 
left outer join RepDailyCollection c on c.RepDailyCollectionID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
where RepDailyInfo.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = 0
```

if you can see 0 then this column must be varchar2 datatype ..

then use following query \

```
Select distinct  RepDailyInfo.Date from RepDailyInfo 
left outer join RepDailyCollection c on c.RepDailyCollectionID = RepDailyInfo.RepDailyInfoID
where RepDailyInfo.RepID = 205 and c.IsReceived = '0'
```

Comment: IsReceived is either true or false. :-(

Comment: Can you please look at the edit part of the question Pratik? Though i can get the results, i am wondering what was wrong with the initial question i asked.

Comment: I had posted thinking that you were asking for sql only .. 

please tell me why you are comparing a boolean type value to 0>?
is it in sql server .. >
in oracle you can directly check boolean with  `true` or  `false`